# Load options on the first open of the Async drop down menu

Tags: react-select

When I provide `loadOptions` to an `Async` control it loads options on mount.

If I pass `autoload={false}` then it doesn't load options neither on mount nor on open. But it loads options on the first close (or type, or blur).

If I pass `onCloseResetsInput={false}` then it doesn't load options until I type something. (showing "Type to search" in the menu)

`Async` provides `onOpen` handler, but I didn't find the way to use it in this situation. (and `react-select@2.0.0-alpha.2` doesn't have it)

So the user needs to type a character, then delete it, to see the full list of options.

How can this be avoided?

**Example sandbox**: https://codesandbox.io/s/mjkmowr91j

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/o51yw14l59

I used the `Async options loaded externally` section from the [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) repo.

We start by loading the options on the Select's `onFocus` and also set the state to `isLoading: true`. When we receive the options we save them in the state and render them in the options.

I also keep track of `optionsLoaded` so that only on the first `focus` do we trigger the call to get options.

Answer (score 1):

In our use case, we have several of these select inputs on a single page, all async, so the requests to the server will pile up, and are completely unnecessary in a lot of cases (users won't even bother clicking).

I found a workaround for this issue that'll work for my use case on 2.0.0-beta.6:

1. Include `defaultOptions`
2. Add 2 members to your class that will store the `resolve`/`reject` methods for the promise.
3. In your `loadOptions` function, check if the input is '', if so, create a new promise, and store the values of `resolve`/`reject` within your class members, and return that promise. Otherwise, just return the promise normally to get your results.
4. Add an onFocus handler, and within it call the function to get your results, but also add `.then` and `.catch` callbacks passing the `resolve` and `reject` functions you stored previously.

Essentially, this makes react-select think you're working on getting the results with a long-running promise, but you don't actually even try to load the values until the field is selected.

I'm not 100% positive there aren't any negative side effects as I just wrote this, but it seems like a good place to start.

Hope this helps someone. I may submit a feature request for this.

Answer (score 1):

In order to load options when user focus first time, set `defaultOptions={true}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Alexei Darmin for the solution, I was struggling with this... while testing it I converted the solution to a react functional component and added real API fetching.

Here is a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-functional-component-14vhk), I hope it helps someone